# Ideas as to why Magento crashes regularly

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, ce-1.8.1.0

On one of our shared servers we have 2 Magento sites, and about 8 other sites running different CMS's. Both of these 2 Magento sites crashes almost every sunday at about 0700. The problem is solved by simply hard-restarting Apache.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

It's been going on for quite some time now, and I've tried to locate what it might be.

Since it only happends at this time I've naturally looked threw all the crons on the server (via `for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done`) but no crons are running at the specific time of the incidents. Note that I've also doublechecked the server date.

I've got plenty of Magento sites on different aws instances, and it's only these two sites that I experience this issue with.

Does anyone have any idea about what I should look into closer? The Magento sites are running version 1.9.0.1 and 1.8.1.0.

Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE: I moved the Magento sites to another server, and the problem stopped occouring (even though there are still a few other sites left), and it didn't happen on the new server. Still few ideas as to what caused it.

Comment: Sorry did you say you have more magento sites on the same server or is there just 2 on this server?

Comment: @Harald Please check you magento logs and error reports

Comment: could you look what crons magento has scheduled for this time? maybe https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler helps with this

Comment: ever tried system monitoring per process? and what exactly crashing? is it a lot of apache processes or few with lots of memory , what you see in your server logs at that time +/- 1 hour... also monitor mysql with mytop. if you know exact time, you have to provide logs

Comment: @BenAnderson There are only these 2 magento sites running on the server. The other sites are not Magento.

Comment: @Flyingmana Thanks, I'll look into Aoe_scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a cron issue. As @Flyingmana suggested, install the great (& free) AOE Scheduler (it's also on Magento Connect), and check that:

- your cron is running
- you don't have 'magento sub cron tasks' blocking

I used to have the same issues as you, I ended up running the cron on its own VPS. There's an hourly task which copies over any changed files from the main Magento VPS, and then all cron tasks run on the cron-specific server. That way if there is any cron issues, the main store is not going to grind to a halt.